# prevent importing non existing node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, eslint

I'm using React Native, npm, node v 8.9.4, eslint.

If I `import View from 'View'`, my app simply takes `View` from `'react-native'` and works (like it does when I use the proper form `import { View } from 'react-native'`). But in production (where different versions of node and different build processes may exist), it crashes on this.

I rather have it throw an error right away if I try to import something in this way, rather than some system trying to be smart about it. I want to have either node, eslint, or some other system warn me about this kind of import.

**How can I make sure that importing from a non-existing node module simply throws an error, instead of trying to be smart about it?**

Comment: The `import` statement isn't 'smart', there must be some aliases somewhere telling that 'View' refers to 'react-native'. What do you use to build your app?

Comment: I'm new in the project, but I guess what is used is what comes out of the box with create-react-native-app, since I don't see any webpack config. I'm sorry I can't be more specific but I'm hoping you know enough with this information right away

Comment: Did you try writing it properly like this: `import { View } from 'react-native';`?

Comment: Absolutely, this works like it should and I want to restrict future me and future other devs to only use imports this way. Added this info to my question.